# Compare a value with the rest of the two dimensional array (Java)

Tags: java

The idea is to compare element `x[0][0]` with all the other next elements of the array, then `x[0][1]` with all the next elements and so on...  My attempt:

```
  outerloop:
      for (int i = 0;i < newBoard.length ;i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < newBoard.length;j++){
           if (i*j == 9){
             System.out.println("BREAK LOOP");
             break outerloop;
           }
           int actualNumber = newBoard[i][j];
            for (int k = i; k < newBoard.length;k++){
              for (int l = j; l < newBoard.length; l++){
                if (actualNumber > newBoard[k][l]){
                  // do stuff
                }
              }
            }
         }
      }
```

`newBoard` is just an `int[][]` object. The above code doesn't work because in the first iteration of the outerloop I get it correctly but in the second iteration l should be set to `0` (in that case the first iteration wouldn't work because it would compare to previous elements which is not desired).

**EDIT:** Maybe I explained it wrong so I'll write a "complete" example of what I want to achieve: x[0][0] should compare to x[0][1], x[0][2], x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2], x[2][0], x[2][1], x[2][2] (assuming a 3x3 array). In the next iteration x[0][1] should compare to  x[0][2], x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2], x[2][0], x[2][1], x[2][2] and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code.

1. If your input 2-d array is not square, your level 2 loop might throw index out of bound exception.
2. There is no need of i*j==9 check, as level 1 and 2 loop will take care of exit conditions.
3. In level 3 and 4 loops, you are comparing the current element with itself which is redundant.

Try below code, it will work.

```
for (int i = 0;i < newBoard.length ;i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < newBoard[i].length;j++){
    int actualNumber = newBoard[i][j]; 
    for (int k = i; k < newBoard.length;k++){
    int l=0;
    if(k==i){
     l=j+1;
    }
    for (; l < newBoard[k].length; l++){ 
        if (actualNumber > newBoard[k][l]){ 
            // do stuff 
        }
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Suppose the case when we are comparing the second row first column of a 4x4 array. In that case for the outer loops we have i = 0, j = 1. So if you start the inner loops (k and l) with l = j + 1, j will never be 0! meaning that it will never compare for example with third row, first column (where k = 2 and l should be 0).

Comment: In your query you said n particular I want to know whether is greater than the next element or not"" -- what does this mean ?

Comment: I am not sure if you are clear with the array indexing concepts. Here, `i & k` represent row and `j & l` represent column. So, when you are at second row and first column, value of `i,j` will be `1,0`. At the same time, `k & l` will be initialised to `1,1` which means your element will be compared with second row second column element and so on.

Comment: @TechFree You're right, I wrote that wrong. I edited with a clearer exp.

Comment: @ManishBansal You're right with what you said. And exactly k &l will be initialised to 1,1. Meaning that they will never compare to elements in the next row, first column (because l will never be 0 in some cases where j > 0)

Comment: Ys. Thank you for pointing the mistake. I have corrected the same. Please check.

Comment: @Miguel Updated my response for the scenario you asked for

Answer (score 0):

This code is from me. The problem of your code is the inner loop should take the length of outer array if it is not a square. Leave comments if you have got some questions or it doesn't help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Assume there's a 3 x 3 array.
    int[][] intArray = new int[][]{
      { 100, 50, 40},
      { 30, 60, 20},
      { 10, 5, 0}
    };

    // Outer loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        // Inner loop.
        for (int j = 0; j < intArray[i].length; j++) {
            // Second round of loop.
            // Compare this element to all the next elements.
            // If you want to compare this with all the elements, set int k = 0.
            for (int k = i; k < intArray.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < intArray[k].length; l++) {
                    if (intArray[i][j] < intArray[k][l]) {
                        // Do something.
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with the second round of the inner loops. You set l = 0, meaning that it could compare to previous elements. Say i = 1 j = 1. So you have x[1][1] which should compare to x[1][2], x[2][0]. x[2][1], x[2][2] in the case of the code you wrote. However, since l = 0, it actually compares to x[1][0], x[1][1] and so on. So it always compares to a previous element first.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use shortended version of the logic. Working code below for a 2d int array.
The code below is when data in each row needs to be compared with remaining data in further indexes in that row only.

```
    int[][] a =
        {{9, 11, 5, 7, 6, 2, 5, 7, 10}, {99, 3344, 233, 44, 667, 777, 888, 777, 45}, {9, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 9, 10, 7}};

    for (int[] aRowIn2dArray : a) {
        int index = 1;
        for (int currentDataValue : aRowIn2dArray) {
            if (index == aRowIn2dArray.length) {
                break;
            }
            int nextDataValue = aRowIn2dArray[index++];
            System.out.println(currentDataValue + ", " + nextDataValue);
            if (currentDataValue > nextDataValue) {
                System.out
                    .println("Found " + currentDataValue + " to be greater than next element " + nextDataValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

In case required to find iteratively if data at every index is greater than any data further in that row and in all subsequent rows, here is working Java 8 based code. Convert the entire data to a list and then iteratively check ifthe value is greater than all remaining values in the further indexes, by sublisting.

```
// test data
        Integer[][] testData =
            {{9, 11, 5, 7, 6, 2, 5, 7, 10}, {99, 3344, 233, 44, 667, 777, 888, 777, 45}, {9, 7, 8, 4, 8, 2, 9, 10, 7}};

        // list of all data
        List<Integer> listOfAllData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer[] aRowIn2dArray : testData) {
            listOfAllData.addAll(Arrays.asList(aRowIn2dArray));
        }

        int column = 1;
        for (Integer[] aRowIn2dArray : testData) {
            for (int currentDataValue : aRowIn2dArray) {
                // list to search on which is sub-listed to contain forward data only
                List<Integer> searchableList = listOfAllData.subList((column), listOfAllData.size());

                //see if this value is greater than all values in the search list
                boolean isCurrentDataValueGreaterThanRest =
                    isDataGreaterThanAllDataInList(currentDataValue, searchableList);

                if (isCurrentDataValueGreaterThanRest) {
                    System.out.println("currentDataValue " + currentDataValue
                        + " is greater than remaining forward data " + isCurrentDataValueGreaterThanRest);
                }
                column++;
            }

        }
```

Method to check if data is greater than all values in requested list.

```
private boolean isDataGreaterThanAllDataInList(int data, List<Integer> listOfData)
    {
        Optional<Integer> result = listOfData.stream().filter(obj -> (obj > data)).findFirst();
        return !result.isPresent();
    }
```

Comment: This only compares to the next element. As my description of the problem says, I need to compare with ALL the other next elements. Meaning that x[0][0] would compare to x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][3], x[1][0], x[1][1]  (...) x[3][3].